# How to tell Xcode to emit IR (LLVM Bitcode) for Swift?

Tags: xcode, swift, macos, llvm, bitcode

I want Xcode to compile my Swift source files to bitcode (IR) instead of Mach-O objects. I'm aware that you can invoke the swift compiler with the `emit-ir` flag, however adding this to the "Other Swift Flags" does not work for me. The flag is set for the initial call to `swiftc` but it's not showing up as an argument in the subsequent calls made to `swift`. As a result I get `Mach-O 64-bit object` files.

For Objective-C I can simply achieve this by either adding the `emit-llvm` flag to `clang` or enabling LTO. What should I do for Swift?

I'm running the latest Xcode (7.3) with Swift 2.2.

**EDIT:** I figured out a workaround where I replace the swift compiler with a script that appends `-emit-bc` to the argument list and forwards it to `swiftc`. However, adding it to the Swift compiler flags in Xcode doesn't work either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Swift frontend and Swift compiler both have a nice option `-help-hidden` (clang has this option as well, btw).

Besides other hidden options there is one called `-Xfrontend`. 
You can use it to pass any parameters directly for the Swift compiler (`swiftc`): `-Xfrontend -emit-bc`.

It actually works, but it leads to linker errors since there are no object files anymore.

Comment: I have the same problem with my workaround, which is fine for my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `swiftc -embed-bitcode`?

Comment: Although this indeed creates an intermediate BC file, the final object file is still a MachO, albeit with bitcode embedded.